# Nested Multipages

Tags: excel, multipage, vba

I am creating a Wizard which takes a lot of data and fills an Excel spreadsheet with the information. At one point I am taking user input to create pages dynamically in a Multipage.

How can I nest Multipages, if possible, because I'd like to put the other sections (which I had had in separate UserForms) onto one form using a Multipage.  The dynamic Multipage would be one of the last pages in the main Multipage.

Comment: What have you tried? It took me 3 seconds to do [THIS](http://imgur.com/JzbIgTu), which is a multipage control *within* a multipage control.  Do you have a specific problem?  If so, you need to add more detail about what that problem is.

Comment: @DavidZemens Is that multipage actually inside the first one, so if I clicked Page1 it would show Page1 and the Pages 3 and 4 would be hidden within Page2?

Comment: Yes. Just use the controls toolbox to design your form control and put the second multipage inside one of the pages on the first multipage :)

Comment: @DavidZemens Alright I got it.  I'll edit my question if I run into any problems. Thanks!